# Nokia phones MIDP 2.0 compatibility

Tags: mobile, java-me, nokia, midp-2.0

Where can I discover which Nokia models support midp 2.0 specification?

Comment: You can try this list. [link](http://j2me.ngphone.com/midp2/nokia.htm) There are probably a lot more. Easier if you know the Nokia model you want.

Comment: 2 closes.. Is this off topic question? I can't believe. :-/

Comment: This is off-topic, as it is a request for off-site resources. From the official close reasons: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look on the [Nokia device specifications.](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Devices/Device_specifications/?filter1=midp2.0) Here you can discover the Nokia mobiles full general and technical specifications.

Answer (score 0):

the following are the Some of the nokia phones support Midp2.0 ,

1. nokia x2
2. nokia c201,etc

for further details please visit nokia developers website.